# How to print the request header that Scrapy sends?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The task I want to do is to print the request header that scrapy sends. I am stumbling a bit on how to use scrapy middlewares.

I activated downloader middlewares in the project `settings.py` file.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'CarDataPull.middlewares.CardatapullDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Then I added the following lines to the function `process_request` within the `middlewares.py` file.

```
 print('I was here')
 with open('request_header.txt', 'wb') as a:
     a.write(request)
```

I am not able to see any signs of this function being activated.

Can anyone tell me how to activate that particular function? Or is there another way to print the request header?

Answer (score 1):

On start scrapy return several log entries including list of active middlewares.
Lines after this log line `[scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:` should have name of your middleware if You expect that it is enabled.
If it doesn't - It means that your middleware is not activated (the most common case - issue with middleware path).

Comment: Hi Georgiy ! Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate a bit on the issue with the middleware path, please? Were you able to reproduce what I described?